# Turn off Auto Backup notification

Tags: google-plus

Is it somehow possible to turn off Google Plus notification about new photos/videos has been Automatically backed up? Maybe it is just consequence of the in-Google Platform event in the Google's web notification box.  In that case is it possible to disable Google notifying me about that at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the Google+ application and go to *Account settings* → *Notifications* → uncheck **Photos added from Auto Backup**.

Comment: This works for push notifications to my phone, but not for the notifications that appear in the top right hand corner of the page when I visit www.google.com

Comment: @JoshLarsen: Can you please attach screenshot, i can't find such option in my settings

Comment: @mailo The option isn't there. I think joshlarsen is talking about the Android app. Was hoping to down-vote for "not reading the question" but don't have enough rep.

Comment: @Mail The option **is** there on my iOS 8.1 iPad version of Google+. What's interesting is that I'm backing up from Android, but receiving notifications everywhere. There is no *global* option for this.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, I enabled back-up of my photos, but Google is forcing me to see these annoying notifications (and it's creating stories and Auto Awesome mods to my photos).

The notifications come via Google+, so I see them on iOS, Android *and* the web interface of Google+. Read [more](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JRRaphael/posts/TE1QkM6mcKU) about how this is annoying others.

The work-around I found so far is to disable **all** notifications in Google+ app.

- Android lets you do this via App Info (uncheck Show notifications).
- iOS lets you via Settings > Notifications > Google+ > Allow Notifications.

I confirmed my settings on Android and PC to be off for "Auto awesome." Yet, Google+ still is creating the "new story" notifications after uploading photos with backup on Android. Something is not right in their software. Maybe they are simply making us "pay" for backups by subjecting us to notifications? This inspires me to shun Google+ even more.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, go to the Control Panel Programs section and Uninstall Google Backup.

This eliminates the annoying Google+ Auto Backup requests.